# CSS absolute position with x scrolling

Tags: html, css

This is the example:

https://jsfiddle.net/yaxfnmtn/

I have a div, and I want to draw some stripes on it. It works fine unless I scroll-x on the div, where I cannot see them anymore. This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bg {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eee 0.1em, transparent 0.1em);
  background-size: 100% 0.7em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

It's a very simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve. Setting it to `position: fixed` doesn't seem like an option?

Comment: Did you try to set the .bg with to 1000px ?

Comment: I did, and that works, but I thought there'd be a better way to do this?

Comment: If you set your 'background-image' and 'background-size' properties to div.inner you should get the result you are after. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/yaxfnmtn/1/

Comment: Why not simply apply the background to the `outer` container?

Comment: Why not just put your background on the div that is too long?  That way when it scrolls, you still have a background on it.  Otherwise your bg needs to be `position:sticky` (not recommended as it's still working draft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is pretty impossible.

When you assign 100% width to the children,that means the parents width not the document.

beside what making the parent overflow is`<div class="inner">` with 1000xp width where the stripes are assigned to `<div class="bg">` which has 100% width which equals to the parent's width.

So instead Apply the strippes to the .outer and when the children overflow, it'll maintain the background.

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eee 0.1em, transparent 0.1em);
  background-size: 100% 0.7em;
}

.inner {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bg {

  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this .? [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yaxfnmtn/2/)

Currently bg takes only 100% widht of its parent ie 300px. So change it to a fixed value like

```
width: 500px;
```

Comment: Quote from a comment by OP in regard to this solution:
"I did, and that works, but I thought there'd be a better way to do this?", so yeah, it works, but it's not what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Maharkus Sorry didnt see it

Answer (score 0):

You setted the striped div in *absolute positioning*, relative to the outer container, so it is getting the 100% of the outer div width (300px).

You should set the striped div *relative* to the inner div, if you want to take its full width (1000px in this case or whatever).

Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="bg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bg {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eee 0.1em, transparent 0.1em);
  background-size: 100% 0.7em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You either have to change the layout or move the stripes to a different item.

For instance, you could add them to the `.outer` div:

```
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
   background-image: linear-gradient(#eee 0.1em, transparent 0.1em);
  background-size: 100% 0.7em;
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yaxfnmtn/5/)